# Unable to override fill property on SVG icon using React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a bunch of icons I have exported from Figma and I would like to create a wrapper Component around those icons, using the benefit of `<use>` tag.

So I created a SVG file with all the symbols in order to target them by their id.

The problem is, I am not able to override the `fill` property on the reused icons. After a lot of reading, I know that I'm supposed to use CSS inheritance since the reused element is in the shadow DOM and its properties cannot be accessed as usual.

Just for debugging purposes, I copy pasted the source code of one of those icons directly in the component (and not using the import mechanism), and surprisingly, it works.

Here is the code :

icon.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="ic">
    <path fill="#000" d="M81,40.933c0-4.25-3-7.811-6.996-8.673c-0.922-5.312-3.588-10.178-7.623-13.844  c-2.459-2.239-5.326-3.913-8.408-4.981c-0.797-3.676-4.066-6.437-7.979-6.437c-3.908,0-7.184,2.764-7.979,6.442  c-3.078,1.065-5.939,2.741-8.396,4.977c-4.035,3.666-6.701,8.531-7.623,13.844C22.002,33.123,19,36.682,19,40.933  c0,2.617,1.145,4.965,2.957,6.589c0.047,0.195,0.119,0.389,0.225,0.568l26.004,43.873c0.383,0.646,1.072,1.04,1.824,1.04  c0.748,0,1.439-0.395,1.824-1.04L77.82,48.089c0.105-0.179,0.178-0.373,0.225-0.568C79.855,45.897,81,43.549,81,40.933z   M49.994,11.235c2.164,0,3.928,1.762,3.928,3.93c0,2.165-1.764,3.929-3.928,3.929s-3.928-1.764-3.928-3.929  C46.066,12.997,47.83,11.235,49.994,11.235z M27.842,36.301c0.014,0,0.027,0,0.031,0c1.086,0,1.998-0.817,2.115-1.907  c0.762-7.592,5.641-13.791,12.303-16.535c1.119,3.184,4.146,5.475,7.703,5.475c3.561,0,6.588-2.293,7.707-5.48  c6.664,2.742,11.547,8.944,12.312,16.54c0.115,1.092,1.037,1.929,2.143,1.907c2.541,0.013,4.604,2.087,4.604,4.631  c0,1.684-0.914,3.148-2.266,3.958H25.508c-1.354-0.809-2.268-2.273-2.268-3.958C23.24,38.389,25.303,36.316,27.842,36.301z   M50.01,86.723L27.73,49.13h44.541L50.01,86.723z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

LocalIcon.css

```
.icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;
}

use.ic-1 {
    fill: skyblue;
}
use.ic-2 {
    fill: #FDC646;
}

svg path {
    fill: inherit;
}
```

LocalIcon.js

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Icons from '../../icons/ic.svg';
import './LocalIcon.css';

const LocalIcon = ({ name, color, size }) => (
  // <svg fill={color} width={size} height={size}>
  //   <use className="icon" xlinkHref={`${Icons}#Icon/Heart/Filled`}/>
  // </svg>
  <>
    <svg>
      <symbol id="ic">
        <path fill="#000" d="M81,40..."/>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg className='icon' viewBox='0 0 100 125'>
      <use className='ic-1' href={`${Icons}#ic`} x='0' y='0' /> // This one is still black
    </svg>
    <svg className='icon' viewBox='0 0 100 125'>
      <use className='ic-2' href='#ic' x='0' y='0' />   // This one works
    </svg>
  </>
);
```

Does someone have an idea about what am I doing wrong ? Is that somehow related to the way I import the file ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your CSS rule to apply,
you need to change any `fill` rule in your SVG code to `fill:'inherit'`. Otherwise, the SVG style will override your CSS style.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. To be completely honest, I followed this tutorial : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/
I know that I could change to inherit, but that would imply a large Find + Replace `fill` attributes in the svg file, and I don't think that's a scalable solution (this is also explained in the article). The thing is, as I said, I manage to override css when the svg is included in the same file, but not when I reference an external SVG